# Is there a confilict between firebase admin node sdk and firebase client sdk when it comes to subscribing to fcm topics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-cli

When subscribing to a firebase console messaging topic using the firebase client sdk using:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("/topics/sometopic")
```

I get a warning:

> '/topics/sometopic' is deprecated. Only 'sometopic' should be used in subscribeToTopic.

However when subscribing to a topic using the firebase admin sdk server side using:

```
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(user.messaging_token, 'sometopic')
```

I get a warning on the cloud server saying

> 'Topic provided to subscribeToTopic() must be a string which matches
>   the format "/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+".'

If I want to be able to subscribe users both from client side and from server side how do I work around this? Is there a conflict or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Both in client side and in server side will subscribe the user to a topic, the difference is that in server side you can subscribe many users to the same topic:

```
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationTokens = [
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
  // ...
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n'
];

// Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the
// topic.
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
    // for the contents of response.
    console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
  });
```

You need to use a topic that does not contain `/`:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news")
```

or

```
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(user.messaging_token, 'news')
```

Comment: Thanks Peter but my issue is that when I use the admin sdk (like in the last line in your comment), it wants the token to have the forward slash. Whereas the command from the client doesn't want the forward slash.

Comment: @thebutcher_254 I think in admin sdk u need to use subscribetotopic("/topics/news") while in the client side you need to use subscribetotopic("news") but in both the topic will be `news`. You should try it and see if it will be the same topic or a new topic will be created